# Hibernate on migrating Corda nodes to Corda 4.3

Tags: hibernate, corda

When upgrading to Corda Open Source 4.3 I ran into this error on node startup. This is using Hibernate 5.4.3 as required by Corda.

```
[ERROR] 2019-12-18T16:17:25,820Z [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging. - Exception during node startup: Could not create Hibernate configuration: 
The [com.foo.BarSchema$NotificationState] and [com.foo.v2.BarSchema$NotificationState] entities share the same JPA entity name: [BarSchema$NotificationState] which is not allowed! [errorCode=3elmpn, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.3/3elmpn]
net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.HibernateConfigException: Could not create Hibernate configuration: 
The [com.foo.BarSchema$NotificationState] and [com.foo.v2.BarSchema$NotificationState] entities share the same JPA entity name: [BarSchema$NotificationState] which is not allowed!
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a known issue in Hibernate as documented here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13060

As recommended in the comments, setting the entity name annotation resolves the exception.